# Add single unique class on button at a time through foor loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop

I am trying to add each unique class (given in array) on each button in the accordion.I have written the jquery code but there is some issue with the code.Currently it is adding all of those array classes on the buttons.I just want it to add only a single class at a time.Please highlight the issue in the code. Thanks

EDIT :

In my current scenerio there will be more than four buttons so i want a generic solution which can add the classes on all buttons and it should only add single classs at a time.

JQUERY CODE :

```js
jQuery(function(){
    var wordArray = ['one','two','three','four'];
    var count = jQuery('.accordion-wrap button').length;

    for ( var i = 0;i < count; i++ ) {
      jQuery('.accordion-wrap button').each(function(index, value) {
        jQuery(this).addClass(wordArray[i])                     
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion-wrap">
<button class="accordion one two three">
  <span class="job-title">Lorem ipsum</span>    
</button>
<button class="accordion one two three">
  <span class="job-title">Lorem ipsum</span>    
</button>
<button class="accordion one two three">
  <span class="job-title">Lorem ipsum</span>    
</button>
<button class="accordion one two three">
  <span class="job-title">Lorem ipsum</span>    
</button>
<button class="accordion one two three">
  <span class="job-title">Lorem ipsum</span>    
</button>
</div>
```

Comment: so why are you doing the for loop around the each. It should just be the each. You defined index...

Comment: @epascarello because i want the for loop to run on the basis of buttons length that is why i am getting the number of buttons in count variable.

Comment: If the number of Buttons is greater than the Array, what should happen? Example, if there are 10 buttons and only 4 elements in the array.

Comment: @Twisty it should repeat the loop until reach the last button.It should repeatedly add classes until the last button but each button should have single class at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider Example #1.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var wordArray = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
  var wordLength = wordArray.length;
  var buttons = $('.accordion-wrap button');
  var i = 0;

  buttons.each(function(index, elem) {
    if (i % wordLength == 0) {
      i = 0;
    }
    $(elem).addClass(wordArray[i++]);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion-wrap">
  <button class="accordion">
  <span class="job-title">Lorem ipsum</span>    
</button>
  <button class="accordion">
  <span class="job-title">Lorem ipsum</span>    
</button>
  <button class="accordion">
  <span class="job-title">Lorem ipsum</span>    
</button>
  <button class="accordion">
  <span class="job-title">Lorem ipsum</span>    
</button>
  <button class="accordion">
  <span class="job-title">Lorem ipsum</span>    
</button>
</div>
```

This iterates over the buttons and will repeatedly assign a class.

Consider Example #2

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var wordArray = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
  var buttons = $('.accordion-wrap button');

  $.each(wordArray, function(i, val) {
    buttons.eq(i).addClass(val);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion-wrap">
  <button class="accordion">
  <span class="job-title">Lorem ipsum</span>    
</button>
  <button class="accordion">
  <span class="job-title">Lorem ipsum</span>    
</button>
  <button class="accordion">
  <span class="job-title">Lorem ipsum</span>    
</button>
  <button class="accordion">
  <span class="job-title">Lorem ipsum</span>    
</button>
  <button class="accordion">
  <span class="job-title">Lorem ipsum</span>    
</button>
</div>
```

This example iterates the the Array and assigns the class to buttons that match the Index.

Comment: Example # 1 code worked. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

So just use the index from the each.

```js
jQuery(function() {
  var wordArray = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
  jQuery('.accordion-wrap button').each(function(index, value) {
    jQuery(this).addClass(wordArray[index])
  })
});
```

```css
/* Just so we can see the class was added */
.one::after {
  content: 'one';
}
.two::after {
  content: 'two';
}
.three::after {
  content: 'three';
}
.four::after {
  content: 'four';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion-wrap">
  <button class="accordion">
  <span class="job-title">Lorem ipsum</span>    
</button>
  <button class="accordion">
  <span class="job-title">Lorem ipsum</span>    
</button>
  <button class="accordion">
  <span class="job-title">Lorem ipsum</span>    
</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know the number of buttons so this code which you shared will only work when we have four or less than four buttons.What if i have more than four button ??

Comment: Check code in description.I have updated the html code.